# How to draw n vertices of a VertexArray in SFML?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I have a line-strip of say N vertices `sf::VertexArray vArr(sf::PrimitiveType::Lines, N);`. Now when i draw it, it draws the entire line-strip of N vertices... How do I draw n (such that n < N) vertices similar to `void glDrawArrays(GLenum mode, GLint first, GLsizei count);` in OpenGL.

For example if N = 20, and n = 4, the RenderTarget should draw 4 vertices of the given vertex array.
In raw OpenGL, I would have just called `glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 4);`... how to do it in SFML?

I tried to use raw OpenGL calls after reading [this](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/window-opengl.php), but could not figure out how to draw the VertexArray from the SFML graphics module.

Comment: *"Now when i draw it"* - ¿And how do you do this? ¿Why don't you use mentioned `glDrawArrays`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target.draw(array)` calls the `draw (const Drawable &drawable, const RenderStates &states=RenderStates::Default)` overload of RenderTarget. This in turn calls `array.draw(target, states)`, which has the [following implementation](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/0d49fab1a622cd2830713831cc7dfa5c58d3e682/src/SFML/Graphics/VertexArray.cpp#L138-L142):

```
void VertexArray::draw(RenderTarget& target, const RenderStates& states) const
{
    if (!m_vertices.empty())
        target.draw(m_vertices.data(), m_vertices.size(), m_primitiveType, states);
}
```

You do not have access to `m_vertices` directly, but you can calculate the correct addresses by grabbing the address of the desired start.
So, you can write a selective drawing function like so:

```
void drawPartialVertexArray(sf::RenderTarget& target, const sf::VertexArray& va, size_t start, size_t count, const RenderStates& states = RenderStates::Default) const {
  target.draw(&va[start], count, va.getPrimitiveType(), states);
}
```

It is of course up to you to make sure that `start` and `start+count` are within the boundaries of `va`, and that `count` is a multiple of the vertex count as required by the primitive type.